# Moving folders with a specific keyword in the name to a new folder

Tags: command-line, move

I want to move all my FLAC music folders to a new folder called lossless. Currently the FLAC folders are inside a folder with lossy formats such as MP3 and AAC.

I want to filter the folders with "flac" in their name and move them to a new directory.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `mv *flac* /path/to/lossless`?

Comment: @Sparhawk `*flac*/`, to match directories.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 mv *flac* directory_name
```

The *flac* is a **file expansion** (not regex, thanks Sparhawk for the correction) for file names containing the word 'flac' within any number of characters so it would capture:

- hello_flac.mp3
- file.format_flac_somerandomwords
- music_file.flac

If you just want files ending in .flac use

> mv *.flac directory_name

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
find /path/to/flac -type d -iname '*flac*' -exec mv -t /path/to/newDirectory {} +
```

Comment: The issue with moving folders with `find` is that you'll remove folders from the search paths that `find` may expect to be able to enter. In the example in your code, the first folder that would have been moved is `/path/to/flac` (since it matches the criteria). You would then get lots of "file not found" errors.  To mitigate this, use `-mindepth 1` (to avoid the top folder) and `-depth` (to do a depth-first traversal of the hierarchy).

Comment: Assuming you used `-mindepth 1` and `-depth`, you also do not check whether a folder with the same name exists at the destination. The two folders `/path/to/flac/A/flacdir` and `/path/to/flac/B/flacdir` would collide.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're dealing with a *single* top-level directory where these folders are to be found:

```
mv -i somefolder/*flac*/ path/to/lossless
```

This would move all folders that has the string `flac` in their names ot the indicated target folder, while alerting you when trying to overwrite anything already existing on in the target directory.

By adding `/` at the end of the filename pattern, we only match directories. This way we will not move any regular files that would have matched the pattern without the trailing `/`.